# Is the DA bound by agreements made during hostage negotiations?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

I've seen several fictional situations where a District Attorney agrees to not prosecute various crimes committed by a kidnapper while conducting hostage negotiations.

Would an agreement made by a DA in furtherance of obtaining the safe release of hostages be enforceable?

Comment: A related issue is whether a DA can lie in hostage negotiations (which ordinary law enforcement officers can). Colorado's attorney regulation entity under the Colorado Supreme Court, has held that they may not and that this is a violation of professional ethics for the lawyer for which the lawyer can be disciplined.

Answer (score 4):

**No, this is duress.**

In 1988, James Harvey took 60 people hostage at the West End Christian School in Tuscaloosa, Alabama. The incident ended when Governor Guy Hunt offered him a video pardoning him.

The video was made under duress, and they never had any intention of honoring it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_End_Christian_School_hostage_crisis

As far as I can tell, Mr. Harvey is [still in prison](https://wvua23.com/tuscaloosa-hostages-30-years-later-forgiven-but-not-forgotten/) for this incident.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.

Comment: “I didn’t feel like he would be able to manage life now if he were out,” Blanton said. “I know jail is not a happy place, but he has food, a bed and a roof over his head.” Ah yes, let's leave him in jail because jail messed him up so badly to not be in jail.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Rather jail then dead children. Society has seen what happens with lax prosecution of criminals.

Comment: @paulj society has also seen what happens with zealous prosecution of certain "criminals," and it isn't better

Comment: @paulj If you listed all the problems with the US justice system, that wouldn't be high on the list